# Young boy turns his parents into superheroes

Tags: story-identification, tv

All I remember is a young boy who somehow manages to turn his parents into superheroes but later wants to change them back. There was also a character called Galacta-something, but I can't remember what. Any thoughts? Please?

Comment: Around when did you see it, and do you remember what decade the styles looked to be from? Also, I'm assuming it was live-action rather than animated?

Comment: I've seen this....ugh I'll figure it out. The kid is sad that is parent don't have time for him anymore later in the episode.

Comment: OP was I right?

Answer (score 7):

[Episode 15, Season 2](http://fairlyoddparents.wikia.com/wiki/Mighty_Mom_and_Dyno_Dad) of the TV show "The Fairly Odd Parents"

> Timmy, tired of his parents rushing to work and coming home late and
>   tired, thus never having any time for him, wishes his parents had
>   superpowers. Unfortunately, now they are too busy saving the world to
>   even spend time with him. Timmy must now become the ultimate villain,
>   Galactimus, Eater of Planets, to get his parents to give up their
>   superpowers.

[image]